How to see all my files that I've shared with other people on Google Drive?
After some research, it appears that as of August 2024, Google Drive still lacks a feature that allows users to filter files shared with people (email addresses) throughout the years. While Drive does let you search for files shared with "anyone with the link" it doesn't provide an option to filter all files shared with individual email addresses. You can search for separate email addresses, but a bulk shared list isn't available. Currently, the only way to see who has access to your files is by manually checking the details pane for each and every file. There used to be a website called "WhoHasAccess" that offered a comprehensive list of shared files, but it seems to have stopped working due to recent API changes from Google. G Suite might offer something in this regard, but I'm not a G Suite user, but a regular one.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?
